# Use gstreamer (1.4.5) to stream video from Youtube

Tags: youtube, video-streaming, gstreamer

Are there any gstreamer plugins exist which allow streaming video from the Youtube? How one should approach this problem?

Also, Youtube uses HTTPS for their videos, not HTTP.

Comment: You should use youtube api instead. Ex: tool "youtube-dl"

Comment: @cxphong sorry, this isn't applicable. Moreover, youtube does not provide  API for streaming their videos. I'm interested in using gstreamer library for that. Though, youtube-dl code can be used for extracting a video URL from the youtube webpage.

Comment: omxplayer can play from extracted url from youtube

Comment: i need to implement it, not use existing software